# SQL server, using a variable in a cast as numeric(@variable,2)

Tags: sql-server, variables, casting

I have a big table that includes a column of floats (1.5million rows) that I join to a slightly smaller table (15k rows) which also has floats, I then multiply various floats.

I have discovered I get significant performance gains (over 10 times faster) using numerics rather than floats in the big table.

Trouble is I don't know the size of the floats in advance so I was hoping to calculate the length of the biggest float and then use that information to cast the float to a numeric using a variable in the declaration i.e. `cast(MyFloatColumn as numeric(@varInt,2))`

It seems I'm not allowed to do this (Incorrect syntax error) so is there an alternative?

Below is some code that shows what I am trying to do - final statement is where the error is.

Many thanks for your help,
Simon

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  MyFloatColumn float
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (12345.12041);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (123.1);
GO

declare @precisionofbiggest int

SELECT @precisionofbiggest = sizeofintpart + 2 
FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) Len(Cast(Cast(myfloatcolumn AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR)) AS 
                              sizeofintpart 
        FROM   dbo.mytable 
        ORDER  BY myfloatcolumn DESC) AS atable 

SELECT cast(myfloatcolumn AS numeric(@precisionofbiggest,2)) AS anewnumericcolumn 
FROM   dbo.mytable
```

(@precisionofbiggest will be 7 in this example so if it worked I would get

```
aNewNumericColumn
12345.12
123.10
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last statement should be dynamic to get the variable value

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT cast(myfloatcolumn AS numeric(' 
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @precisionofbiggest) 
           + ',2)) AS anewnumericcolumn      FROM   dbo.mytable' 

exec sp_executesql @sql
```